# Duplicate Blur Effect on Animation Completion in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, blur

I'm working on a website where I have an element with backdrop-filter: blur(25px) applied to it. The element is initially hidden and smoothly animates into view on hover. The issue occurs in the Chrome browser: after the animation completes, it seems that the blur effect is applied again or intensified, resulting in extra blur on parts of the animating element.

Here is the sample https://codepen.io/Taras-Nakonechnyi-the-builder/pen/LYqWWLE

```
<a href="#" class="link">
  <img src="https://hbr.org/resources/images/article_assets/2019/11/Nov19_14_sb10067951dd-001.jpg" class="image">
  <div class="description">
    <h2 class="title">Product test</h2>
    <div class="info">
      <span>Content</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

```
.link {
  display: block;
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.link:hover .description {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.link:hover .title {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.image {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.description {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.info {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  background: rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.20);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(25px);
}
```

In Safari, this works perfectly, and I expect it to work the same way as it does in Safari.